# HTML form not submiting

Tags: php, html

I have just a basic html form within index.php which contains two text fields:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <label for="title">Title:</label> <input type="text" size="30" name="title"/><br>
    <label for="number">Number:</label> <input type="text" size="30" name="number"/><br>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="add" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

Then I have some PHP script which checks if the form has been submitted, if so it runs some script however this script is never ran.

```
if($_POST['add'] == "Submit")
{
    echo "This should print but it doesn't";
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: The value of the submit button is set to value="Add" not value="Submit"

Comment: yep that fixed it, I don't know what I was thinking there. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of:

```
if($_POST['add'] == "Submit")
```

do:

```
if($_POST['add'] == "Add")
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of your submit button is "Add" but you are checking if it equals "Submit"

Try:

```
if($_POST['add'] == "Add")
{
    echo "This should print but it doesn't";
}
```